# Sign In with Apple fatal error for Catalyst app: Attempting to present ASAuthorizationController from a SwiftUI view not in a hierarchy

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui, mac-catalyst, sign-in-with-apple

I have a SwiftUI app where I can sign in via Apple Sign In using Firebase Auth. This works completely fine on iPad and iPhone.

However when when running the app via catalyst on Mac, using Apple Sign In I get a crash with the following log.

> _AuthenticationServices_SwiftUI/SignInWithAppleButton.swift:303: Fatal error: Attempting to present ASAuthorizationController from a SwiftUI
> view not in a hierarchy. This should not be possible, please file
> feedback. 2022-07-13 19:31:29.368989+0100 appname[93200:13915263]
> _AuthenticationServices_SwiftUI/SignInWithAppleButton.swift:303: Fatal error: Attempting to present ASAuthorizationController from a SwiftUI
> view not in a hierarchy. This should not be possible, please file
> feedback. (lldb)

I am not sure what is wrong, I have checked Apple Documentation and am struggling to find a fix.

**Apple Sign In Object:**

```
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices
import CryptoKit 

@EnvironmentObject var store: Store

struct SignInWithAppleButtonView: View {

    //Hashing function using CryptoKit
private func sha256(_ input: String) -> String {
    let inputData = Data(input.utf8)
    let hashedData = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
    let hashString = hashedData.compactMap {
        return String(format: "%02x", $0)
    }.joined()
    
    return hashString
}

// from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple
private func randomNonceString(length: Int = 32) -> String {
    precondition(length > 0)
    let charset: Array<Character> =
        Array("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._")
    var result = ""
    var remainingLength = length
    
    while remainingLength > 0 {
        let randoms: [UInt8] = (0 ..< 16).map { _ in
            var random: UInt8 = 0
            let errorCode = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 1, &random)
            if errorCode != errSecSuccess {
                fatalError("Unable to generate nonce. SecRandomCopyBytes failed with OSStatus \(errorCode)")
            }
            return random
        }
        
        randoms.forEach { random in
            if remainingLength == 0 {
                return
            }
            
            if random < charset.count {
                result.append(charset[Int(random)])
                remainingLength -= 1
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result
}


@State var currentNonce:String?

var body: some View {
    SignInWithAppleButton(.signIn) { request in
        
        
        // You can change them if needed.
        let nonce = randomNonceString()
        currentNonce = nonce
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        request.nonce = sha256(nonce)
        
        
    } onCompletion: { result in
        // Switch result
        switch result {
            // Auth Success
        case .success(let authResults):
            default:
                break
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("failure", error)
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
```

**Login**

```
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices
import CryptoKit 

struct login: View {

@EnvironmentObject var store: Store

  var body: some View {

    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
          VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
              SignInWithAppleButtonView()
              .signInWithAppleButtonStyle(.black)
               .environmentObject(store)

          }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

**Handler**

```
class Store : ObservableObject {

func signInWithAppleHandler(credential: OAuthCredential) {
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            // Error. If error.code == .MissingOrInvalidNonce, make sure
            // you're sending the SHA256-hashed nonce as a hex string with
            // your request to Apple.
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            return
        }
        print("Signed in")
        
        if let user = authResult?.user {
            // Fetch profile
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            
            db.collection("users").document(user.uid).getDocument { [self] (document, error) in
                if let document = document, document.exists {
                    //User exists now save that to current user
                    _ = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
                                            
                    do {
                        self.profile = try document.data(as: Profile.self)
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("There was an error getting decoding Profile")
                    }
                    
                    if self.profile != nil {
                        self.userAuthState = .signedIn
                        self.isNewUser = self.profile!.newUser
                        self.loadProfileImageFromFirebase(uid: profile!.uid)

                    }
                    
                } else {
                    // create profile
                    firestoreManager.createProfile(uid: user.uid, email: user.email ?? "")
                    
                    fetchProfile(uid: user.uid)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Apple Documentation:**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/signinwithapplebutton

**Firebase Documentation:**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple

Comment: Most of that code doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question. Or does it? Did you do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through you code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected or the code crashes? If so, please update your question with those results, the expected results and what line is crashing. Update your question with details and we'll take a look!

Comment: It crashed right after the completion block `onCompletion: { result in`. I am using Firebase Auth and App Sign In. Apple Documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/signinwithapplebutton

Comment: Can you clarify what "right after" means? Do you mean the first line within the closure `switch result {` or the this `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` or somewhere else. You're also missing how this `request.` is defined. You don't have a controller defined to actually sign in which may be why this `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` is not working? Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The code above displays the controller in SwiftUI to sign in. It crashes first line after the completion block   `} onCompletion: { result in`

Comment: Again "first line after completion block" is vague - there is no line after the `SignInWithAppleButton` completion block. Just the end of the closure `}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)  }`

Comment: Apologies, the line for `switch result {`

Comment: So you're saying if you add a breakpoint to this line `case .success(let authResults):` and run the code, the app crashes before it gets to that line? If so, what happens if you add `print(results)` before the switch statement so you can inspect the contents of `results`. This is all basic troubleshooting you may have already done but will help us narrow the issue.